# Convert a matrix to dataframe with normalization

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (matrix) that looks like that :

```
C0| A | B | C
A | 1 | 2 | 3
B | 4 | 5 | 6
C | 7 | 8 | 9
```

I want to normalize this dataframe and generate a new one with 3 columns , it will look like that :

```
A | A | 1
A | B | 2
A | C | 3
B | A | 4
B | B | 5
B | C | 6
C | A | 7
C | B | 8
C | C | 9
```

Comment: is there really a `C0` column or are those the row names?  Can you please use `dput()` post an easily reproducible version of your data frame or matrix?

Answer (score 0):

For matrices you might do

```
cbind(rep(rownames(m), each=nrow(m)),
      rep(colnames(m), ncol(m)), 
      matrix(t(m), ncol=1)) |> as.data.frame()
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  A  A  1
# 2  A  B  2
# 3  A  C  3
# 4  B  A  4
# 5  B  B  5
# 6  B  C  6
# 7  C  A  7
# 8  C  B  8
# 9  C  C  9
```

and for the data frame case, convert it to a matrix beforehand,

```
m <- as.matrix(df[-1]) |> `rownames<-`(df$C0)
```

or try `stack`.

```
stack(df[-1]) |> {\(.) .[order(.$values), ]}() |>
  cbind(ind1=rep(df$C0, each=nrow(df))) |> subset(select=3:1)
#   ind1 ind values
# 1    A   A      1
# 4    A   B      2
# 7    A   C      3
# 2    B   A      4
# 5    B   B      5
# 8    B   C      6
# 3    C   A      7
# 6    C   B      8
# 9    C   C      9
```

*R >= 4.1 was used.*

---

*Data:*

```
m <- structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 9L), dim = c(3L, 
3L), dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "C")))

df <- structure(list(C0 = c("A", "B", "C"), A = c(1L, 4L, 7L), B = c(2L, 
5L, 8L), C = c(3L, 6L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

if matrix:

```
data.frame(as.table(m))
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    A    A    1
2    B    A    4
3    C    A    7
4    A    B    2
5    B    B    5
6    C    B    8
7    A    C    3
8    B    C    6
9    C    C    9
```

And if `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(data.frame(df, row.names = 'C0'))))
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    A    A    1
2    B    A    4
3    C    A    7
4    A    B    2
5    B    B    5
6    C    B    8
7    A    C    3
8    B    C    6
9    C    C    9
```

NB: Stole the data from [@jay.sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718754/r-language-convert-a-matrice-to-dataframe-with-normalization/72718966#72718966)

Note that if you want it in the order of `var1` then:

```
with(a<-data.frame(as.table(m)), a[order(Var1, Var2), ])
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    A    A    1
4    A    B    2
7    A    C    3
2    B    A    4
5    B    B    5
8    B    C    6
3    C    A    7
6    C    B    8
9    C    C    9
```

or simply:

```
data.frame(as.table(t(m)))[c(2,1,3)]
  Var2 Var1 Freq
1    A    A    1
2    A    B    2
3    A    C    3
4    B    A    4
5    B    B    5
6    B    C    6
7    C    A    7
8    C    B    8
9    C    C    9
```